# Live Indexing DSE

Tags: solr, cassandra, heap-memory, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I want to enable live indexing on my cluster. As per the steps [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchConfIncrIndexThruPut.html), I must increase the heap size to at least 20 GB. I have 3 nodes in my cluster, each having 32 GB of RAM. The current heap size configuration is shown below

[image]

Is it recommendable for me to change my heap size to 20GB with the same amount of RAM? If not, what should the recommended heap size be for my RAM so that live indexing works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search query performance depends on our ability to utilize the OS page cache effectively to keep search indexes hot. The smaller the size of your indexes, the easier it will be for the OS to maintain them in memory.

If you increase your heap, that's less RAM available for page cache and less likelihood that you'll be fitting those indexes in RAM. Check their size in the solr.data directory and see if you have enough RAM.

Also check out my post on decreasing index size:

http://www.sestevez.com/solr-space-saving-profile/